# Am I doing this Gram-Schmidt calculation correctly?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Here it is then, I want to check if I am doing this procedure the right way.

We have V is a vector space $R_2[X] = ${$f|f=\lambda_0+\lambda_1X+\lambda_2X^2$}
The inner product is defined as $VxV \rightarrow K$ by $\langle f,g\rangle = \int^1_0 f \cdot g \ dx$  The basis S on V is $S=${$s_1, s_2, s_3$}$=${$3, 1+X, -X^2$}

So I want an orthonormal basis. The first vector I need is $v_1$ and it's just going to be 1. so $v_1=s_1=1$.

The next one is outlined by the formula, $$v_2=s_2-\frac{\langle s_2, v_1 \rangle}{\rVert v_1 \rVert^2}v_1$$ which here will be:

$s_2=1+X$, and $ \rVert v_1 \rVert^2 = \langle (1+X), (1+X) \rangle$ but since the problem defines the inner product as the integral it's $\langle f,g\rangle = \int^1_0 \langle (1+X) \cdot (1+X) \rangle \ dx$ or $\int^1_0 (1+2X+X^2) dx$ which works out to $\frac{7}{3}$.

Meanwhile the numerator of the projection is $ \int^1_0 \langle (1+X), 1 \rangle \ dx$ which is $X+ \frac{X^2}{2}$, Since $v_1=1$ we end up with: $$v_2=(1+X)- \frac{\frac{3}{2}}{\frac{7}{3}}=3(1+X)+\frac{\frac{9}{2}}{7}=6(1+X)+\frac{9}{7}$$ To normalize it I'll divide by $v_2$'s norm.

Anyhow I want to know if I am doing this right.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect.  You have used $v_1=1+X$ in computing $\|1+X\|^2$, but actually $v_1=1$.

Please, see the steps that I've added to [my answer to your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441030/finding-a-an-orthonormal-basis-with-gram-schmidt/441032#441032).

Also: if your variable is $X$, you should be integrating $dX$ instead of $dx$.

Comment: OK, but the way the problem is set up it uses the variables in exactly that way. That's why I suspected before that the big X was a polynomial (space?) and not a variable.

Comment: If that were the case, then the problem would not be solvable - you can't explicitly compute things of this nature using an unknown polynomial.  I think it is much more likely that it is a typo on your instructor's part, but you should probably check with them.